# Creat a new list from another List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I got a class `Person` with three different instance variables.

- Id
- Name
- BirthDate

I also got a List `persons` which has some `Person` objects in it.

How can I create a new List that shows me (let's say a treeview) a birthdate with all the registered names under it.

> 10/04/1950   >Richard >Dan >John
>
> 18/16/1940 >Jane > Ron
>
> .....

Comment: Look at linq's `.GroupBy()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var list = persons.GroupBy(person=>person.BirthDate)
                  .Select(gr=> new 
                  {
                      Day = gr.Key,
                      Names = string.Concat(",",gr.Select(x=>x.Name))
                  }).ToList();
```

This will create a list of objects with two properties one the Date and the other a comma separated list of the names of persons that have the same Birthday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the names as a list of names then try the following:

```
var dateTree = (from p in persons
                group p by p.BirthDate into g
                select new
                {
                       BirthDate = g.Key,
                       Names = persons.Where(x => x.BirthDate == g.Key).Select(y => y.Name)
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I put results into a dictionary and then displayed in a DataGridView.  See code below

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Person> people = new List<Person>() {
                new Person() { BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("10/04/1950"), ID = 1, Name = "Richard"},
                new Person() { BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("10/04/1950"), ID = 2, Name = "Dan"},
                new Person() { BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("10/04/1950"), ID = 3, Name = "John"},
                new Person() { BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("12/16/1950"), ID = 4, Name = "Jane"},
                new Person() { BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("12/16/1940"), ID = 5, Name = "Ron"}
            };

            Dictionary<DateTime, List<Person>> dict = people.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.BirthDate, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("BirthDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            foreach (Person person in dict[DateTime.Parse("10/04/1950")])
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { person.BirthDate, person.Name });
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get;set;}
        public string Name { get;set;}
        public DateTime BirthDate { get;set;}
    }
}
​
```